# Java freezes when searching for maven dependency

Tags: java

I am using the newest version of Maven Eclipse and whenever I have been able to get one dependency for what I am working on, but whenever I try to add a second Eclipse just shows "Searching Repository" and eventually freezes. I have tried changing my preferences to make sure that the indexes update upon startup, I have enough storage space on my hard drive, I have enabled full index, and I have also tried rebuilding the indexes as well. I am on a windows computer.

Comment: Is this a local repository or a remote one? Which one?

Comment: I believe it is a global repository

Comment: What happens if you try to run mvn clean install outside of your IDE?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use mvn clean install, I don't think I have anything like that installed. I think I just have Eclipse downloaded

Comment: I have just checked and and I saw that I can run maven clean inside my IDE, but I still don't know exactly what it does and if I need to do anything after I run it.